# R: - Error in model/variable lengths differ - random forest

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest

I am trying to build a random forest , but  I keep on getting the same error regardless of my efforts to deal with NA's and reformulate my data , because this appears to be the most common reason for this error. However it persists and I am unable to run my model.

```
  ##Prepare data for random forest
Comprr<-Compr
Comprr$Mudster<-ifelse(Comprr$verifikation <10,'good','ok')
Comprr$Mudster[Comprr$verifikation==10]<-'restricted'
Comprr$Mudster<-as.factor(Comprr$Mudster)
table(Comprr$Mudster)

##Separate test and train data 
set.seed(123)
samp<-sample(nrow(Comprr),0.6 * nrow(Comprr))
train<-Comprr[samp, ]
test<-Comprr[-samp, ]
na.roughfix(Comprr)
##Building the model
library(randomForest)
model<-randomForest(Comprr$Mudster~ . -verifikation,data = train)
```

This is the relevant part of the code and here is the Error message that it returns

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Mudster ~ . - verifikation, data = train,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'message'
```

)
And this is regardless of the variable I have tried cleaning them one by one whenever it returned the error until I realised its something more fundamental.
Your help will be very appreciated ! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try run this before the RF model line

names(Comprr) <- make.names(names(Comprr))

Comment: Please elaborate what this does.